# Orchestrating Pipelines in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need help on ADF(Not Devops) orchestration. I am giving process flow with ADF activity which are denoted by numbers

SAP tables---> Raw Zone---->Prepared Zone----->Trusted Zone------->sFTP

```
        1              2                 3                   4
```

Kafka Ingestion (Run by ADF)

Databrick jar(Run by ADF)

Databrick jar(Run by ADF)

ADF Copy activity

The below tasks need to be done

After files are generated in trusted zone, a synchronous process would copy the files into sFTP location.

To copy files into sFTP, it would get all .ctl files (trigger/control files) and compare with what’s been flagged as processed in JOB_CONTROL table. Copy the new files that were not processed/copied before.

The copy program should poll for .ctl files and following steps to be performed

a. Copy csv file with same as ctl file.

b. Copy ctl file

c. Insert/Update a record in JOB_CONTROL using file type that the file is processed successfully. If it is successful, the file will not be considered for next run.

d. In the event of error, it should mark with respective status flag so that the same file to be considered in next run as well

Please help me to achieve this.

Regards,
SK

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding about the ask , you are logging the file copied in a table and the intend is to initiate the copy of the files which failed .
I think you can use a Lookup activity to read the file(s) which failed and then pass that to a foreach(FE) loop . Inside the FE loop you can add the copy activity ( you will have to paramterized the dataset ) .
HTH